# Oracle Apex 22.2 Text field with autocomplete

Tags: text, autocomplete, field, apex

I am working with Oracle APEX 22.2 and text field with autocomplete.
In 22.2 they changed the attributes of this item.

I've created an List of Values with type SQL Query. The query should have two columns
and I don't want to see the keyvalue in the List.

Column 1 = description > as a display in the gui
Column 2 = keyvalue > as a return value

I've created 2 columns in the query for the List of values, but that is not possible.

Any ideas, how do I get the return value back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in query for Text field with autocomplete item, you should only use query with one column. like `select Column1 from table_name`.

if you want to return id of selected item, you should use PopupLOV item with below settings:
[image]

This settings for PopupLOV, caused it work like Text field with autocomplete item.

In conclusion, when you are need to id for return, you can not use from Text field with autocomplete item.

Comment: Hi Arash, many thanks for your answer. It helped a lot. Best.